# Is it okay to return in new Promise?

Tags: javascript

While I'm aware this code is messy, would it lead to unexpected results?

```
someFunction(args, agency) {
    var promise = new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
            return promise1(args1)
                .then((resp1) => {
                    return promise2(args2)
                        .then((resp2) => {
                            return promise3(args3)
                                .then((resp3) => {
                                    return promise4(args4)
                                        .then((resp4) => {
                                            resolve(resp4);
                                        })
                                })
                                .catch(function (error) {
                                    reject(error);
                                });
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            reject(error);
                        });
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    reject(error);
                });
        }
    );
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: This code looks like a *higher than* symbol `>`.

Comment: yes, that's nice ASCIIart

Comment: Joke aside, this is called "callback hell"

Comment: It's hard to say if  it leads to unexpected results, because I can't tell what you expect. As an aside, please learn about promise chaining!

Comment: No, it’s the same with or without the first `return` statement (or any of them).

Comment: The equivalent would be `someFunction(args, agency) {
    return promise1(args1)
        .then(resp1 => promise2(args2))
        .then(resp2 => promise3(args3))
        .then(resp3 => promise4(args4))
}`. Each of your `.catch(function (error) {
                    reject(error);
                })` are basically a no-op, and there's no point wrapping this chain with a promise constructor since each of the functions already return promises.